# How to create an object of a class - but WHICH class varies, and is dependant on other variables

Tags: java, function, class, object

If I want my program to create an object of a class, but the choice of which class is not certain yet. How do I do?

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    String choice = getChoice(i);
    if (i == 1) {
        obj.add(new choice(w, i)); // the "choice" here is not accepted as a class
        ...etc
```

The getChoice-function looks like this:

```
private String getChoice(int ID) {
    String choice = "Class10"; // It says Class10 now, but in the future
    // the class name will be taken from a database. Hence, the chosen class
    // will be determined by the ID.
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: This is just absolutely bad design. If you explain what you're trying to achieve with this, we can provide you with a good solution.

Comment: I'm creating a 2d-simulator. The for-loop is first in the main method, adding objects to the simulation.

Answer (score 3):

Its time for you to define an architecture, if the method can return different classes I can infer those classes are somehow related and have something in common about what they can do or what they are...

you can then be prepare for what the class can be and do:

```
public interface ISomethingInCommon{
    void something();
}

private ISomethingInCommon getChoice(int ID) {
    swith(){
    case 0:
        return new FooA();
    case 1:
        return new FooB();
    defult:
        return new FooDefault();
}
```

in order to be valid **FooA**, **FooB** and **FooDefault** must implement **ISomethingInCommon**

Answer (score 0):

[`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) will give you the named `class`.  Then [`#newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) will create an object of that class.

```
String choice = getChoice(i);
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(choice);
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

If you need to pass arguments to the constructor, then you need to use [getConstructor(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...))

```
/* Assuming "w" is a String */
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class);
Object object = constructor.newInstance(w, i);
```

**Note**: You need to use the fully qualified class name, such as `your.package.name.Class10`.

While this answers your exact question (creating an object based on the `String` name of the class), this approach has its risks.
For instance, you indicated the class names would come from a database; a malicious entry in the database could create an object of practically any class.

If all possible classes are known ahead of time, returning the class (not a string) from the set of all valid classes from `getChoice()` would be safer.

---

Based on your classes in the comments, below:

```
package simulator;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Simulator {

    public static void main(String... args)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException,
            SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Class<? extends Unit> unit_class = getChoice(i);
            Constructor<? extends Unit> constructor = unit_class.getConstructor(String.class);
            Unit unit = constructor.newInstance("Name");
            System.out.println(unit);
        }
    }

    private final static List<Class<? extends Unit>> UNIT_BY_ID = Arrays.asList(TallMan.class,
            ShortMan.class);

    private static Class<? extends Unit> getChoice(int id) {
        return UNIT_BY_ID.get(id);
    }
}

class Unit {
    Unit(String name) {
    }
}

class Man extends Unit {
    Man(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

class TallMan extends Man {
    public TallMan(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

class ShortMan extends Man {
    public ShortMan(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Output:

> simulator.TallMan@15db9742
>   simulator.ShortMan@6d06d69c

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. All possible classes ARE know ahead of time, so I think I will go with your second alternative. However I am not sure what anything in the following means (except for ofc "private static"): Class<IBaseClass> CLASS_BY_ID[] = { Class10.class, ... };

Comment: `Class<IBaseClass> CLASS_BY_ID[] = { ... }` is a inline declaration and initialization of an array of type `Class<IBaseClass>`.  The contents in `{ ... }` are the values of the array.  Since we never change the array, and no one else needs access to it, it should be declared `private final static`, of course.  `{ Class10.class, Class11.class, Class12.class}` would initialize the array so that `CLASS_BY_ID[0]` was `Class10.class`, `CLASS_BY_ID[1]` was `Class11.class`, etc.

Comment: It seems to work now Except that I get "type missmatch, cannot convert from Class<ShortMan> to Class<Man>"

Class order is Unit -> Man -> ShortMan/TallMan

Comment: My bad.  Seems you have to use `Class<?>` in the array declaration, and then cast the class before returning from `getChoice()`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see, that seems to do that part. However,      obj.add(new getChoice(id)(w, id)); will not work now

Comment: Example updated.  As I said, you need to use getConstructor(...) if you want to pass arguments to the constructor

Comment: But this doesn't add the object to any array? I had the obj vector in my example, and there I have parameters w, id and if i want more afte that. w is the simulation window.

Comment: Or does the following add the object to the Unit-array unit? Unit unit = constructor.newInstance("Name"); and if I have more than one argument I replace ("Name") with (variable, variable2) etc? Man this is new to me :) Sorry. And thanks alot for helping out!

Comment: Exercise left to student.  Yes, my example creates to objects, but doesn't save them anywhere.  If you want to pass more arguments to the constructor, you need to get the corresponding constructor, and pass in more arguments to the newInstance call.   Perhaps the approach in the other answer would be more appropriate for your task; using reflection is an advanced topic, and probably overkill, adding more complexity than necessary.

Comment: OK I get it, so I ahve to add it to an array within th eloop then. np. however, your latest edit confuses me. If I want to put in arguments of the type SimpleWindow.class and say int, I add that and Integer.class within the getConstructor(x.class)? I did this but when executing I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TallMan.<init>(SimulationWindow, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at Simulate.main(Simulate.java:27)

Comment: and I did add the throw NoSuchMethodException

Comment: Are you calling `getConstructor(SimpleWindow.class, Integer.class, Integer.class)`?  If so, does your constructor take 2 integers?  If not, you have one too many `Integer.class` arguments in the getConstructor call.

Comment: Yes I'm writing    
`'getConstructor(SimpleWindow.class, Integer.class, Integer.class)'`    and the TallMan.class has following constructor:    
`public TallMan(SimulationWindow w, int nbr, int p) {
  super(w, nbr);
  this.p = p;
 }`